# jquerys dialog does not hide correctly

Tags: jquery, dialog, hide

I have an asp.net page.  The dialog opens when I click on a div, but it will not close. looking at other examples.. I think it should work but it is not.  Here is the code (I'm using a master page).  Again.. the dialog does open ok.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode"
                ,duration: 1000
            }
        });
        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="opener">TestIt</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5WGuY/).

Comment: yes.. yours did work for me as well. I still can't get my code to fire off correctly.. so it must be something else in the page. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: What else is in your page that might seem suspect?

Comment: I've commented everything out of the page except for the above and it works.  so putting one thing in at a time.. when I add an <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlSomethign" runat="server"/> with nothing behing bound to it in code behind.. the hide no longer works.  So i'm gonna start digging.

Comment: Not that it helps any at all.. but after doing nothing other than commenting and uncommenting the drop down list.. sometimes the hide works and sometimes it does not.  The only thing I've changed is moving the --%> characters back and forth from before the drop down to after the drop down.  I haven't been able to work out a pattern yet as to what is going on.